# phonegap The last location provider was disabled

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, geolocation

i have this code

```
// Wait for Cordova to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {   
    $(window).ready(function(){
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, {enableHighAccuracy:true, timeout: 5000});
    });
}
```

try test this crap on Android 4.1 (Emulator) but allways get error "The last location provider was disabled"/

1. enableHighAccuracy:true - you see in code
2. 'Enable Location' - in browser settings is checked
3. all uses-permission in manifest.xml
4. all geolocation settings in system settings is checked

try on real android 4.1 device, it is also give error.

How this can be?

Comment: Did you try removing the  $(window).ready event? its not required after deviceready event.

Comment: i try all variants, and all tips that i can find on stackoverflow about this error.

Comment: i need fresh help! pleeese!!!

Comment: What version of PhoneGap are you using?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the geolocation functionality piece may be broken in the emulator. The old 'enableHighAccuracy' trick doesn't seem to work anymore. Perhaps if you telnet into the emulator to set the location: https://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#geo

Answer (score 4):

I figured this out: I needed to go into the setting of my mobile browser and check 'Enable Location'

Menu--->Settings---->Location & Security

And then check

Use Wireless Network.

Comment: Hey, i do this, the error was fixed, but the map don't show! do u know what can be? @Swapnill Dalvi